# Setting margins for an individual page

Tags: margins, titles

With the `geometry` package, we can set margins for the whole document (with options like `left`, `right`, etc.). Now, how do we set margins for an individual page so that it doesn't affect the whole document. The reason for this question is that, when using `book` class, the left and right margins are equal in the left page and the right page respectively and the spline is a bit larger. How do I set `left` and `right` margins to be **equal** in the **titlepage**. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent \rule{\textwidth}{4pt}
\rule{\textwidth}{4pt}
\kant[1-3]
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar perhaps not; the title induced me to think it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\newgeometry` for that page and immediately afterwards, issue `\restoregeometry` so that original layout setting are applied. The key to be used is `centering`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[pass,a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.5in]{geometry}   %% change 0.5in to suit your needs.
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{centering}    %%% <--- here
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent \rule{\textwidth}{4pt}
\rule{\textwidth}{4pt}
\kant[1-3]
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry       %% <--- and here
\kant[4-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also be interested in `marginratio=1:1` or/and `vcentering`.